# Count total where owner_user_id = some_value and deleted_by_owner = 0 or to_user_id = some_value and deleted_by_to = 0

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.5

I didn't know if this is possible using just a query or if I need some procedural logic on this one.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `default_messages_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `owner_user_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
  `to_user_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
  `read_message` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_read` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_by_owner` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_by_to` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `message_id_owner_user_id_to_user_id_UQ`
      (`message_id`,`owner_user_id`,`to_user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
  AUTO_INCREMENT=2 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
  COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And a simple record for testing purpose:

```
INSERT INTO `default_messages_users` (`id`, `message_id`, `owner_user_id`, 
    `to_user_id`, `read_message`, `date_read`, `deleted_by_owner`, `deleted_by_to`) 
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 2, 0, '2012-09-04 14:09:14', 0, 0);
```

For the query:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM default_message_users
WHERE owner_user_id = @SomeValue and deleted_by_owner = 0 
    or to_user_id = @SomeValue and deleted_by_to = 0
```

If `@SomeValue = 1` then the query should return this row if `owner_user_id = 1 && deleted_by_owner = 0` or `to_user_id = 1 && deleted_by_to = 0`, is the same as `owner_user_id == to_user_id == 1` but always checking in pairs as explained before.

Is that possible using just a query or do I need programming help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, I think this solves your problem:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM default_message_users
WHERE (owner_user_id = @SomeValue and deleted_by_owner = 0)
    or (to_user_id = @SomeValue and deleted_by_to = 0)
```

Note the addition of `(` and `)` to denote the order of operations for the `AND` and `OR` operators.

To clarify, order of operations dictates that `AND` conditions will be evaluated prior to `OR` conditions.  My intent with this answer is that in more complicated cases it is easier to explicitly define the desired logic rather than to rely on the implicit order of operations.